# Sidebar Insight and Help Request

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm looking to implement the same sidebar on my index, archive, and post pages but I am having some trouble. I've realized that I can't put this code directly into the sidebar file and that I need to register the sidebar in the functions.php file. However, I'm not really sure how I am supposed to break down my code in regards to registering it in the functions.php file.

Am I supposed to register a sidebar for each section (in this case, search, categories, archives)? Or am I overcomplicating things?

Any help and insight is appreciated!

Below is my Sidebar Code:

```
<div class="col-md-4">
    <div class="well">
        <h4>Search</h4>
        <div class="input-group">
            <?php get_search_form(); ?>
        </div>
        <!-- /.input-group -->
    </div>

    <!-- Blog Categories Well -->
    <div class="well">
        <h4>Categories</h4>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <ul class="list-unstyled"><?php _e(); ?>
                    <li>
                        <?php wp_list_cats(); ?>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.row -->
    </div>
    <div class="well">
        <h4>Archives</h4>
        <div class="input-group">
            <select name="archive-dropdown" onchange="document.location.href=this.options[this.selectedIndex].value;" id="dd">
              <option value=""><?php echo esc_attr( __( 'Select Month' ) ); ?></option> 
              <?php wp_get_archives( array( 'type' => 'monthly', 'format' => 'option', 'show_post_count' => 1 ) ); ?>
            </select>
        </div>
        <!-- /.input-group -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

All you need to do in your `functions.php`, or in a file you include in your `functions.php` file, is to add a [`register_sidebar`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_sidebar) function like this:

```
register_sidebar(array (
    'name'          => esc_html__( 'Primary Sidebar', 'mytheme'),
    'id'            => 'primary-widget-area',
    'description'   => esc_html__( 'The Primary Widget Area', 'mytheme'),
    'before_widget' => '<div id="%1$s" class="widget %2$s">',
    'after_widget'  => "</div>",
    'before_title'  => '<div class="sidebar-widget-heading"><h6>',
    'after_title'   => '</h6></div>',
));
```

This will register your sidebar where you can put widgets in.

Then in your theme just call it using [`dynamic_sidebar()`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/dynamic_sidebar):

```
dynamic_sidebar(esc_html__( 'Primary Sidebar', 'mytheme'));
```

In case you decide to put the `register_sidebar` in a separate file, for convenience, you can add it in your `sidebars.php` file. I usually put all these extra files in a `/inc` folder and then call it in my `functions.php` file like:

```
add_action('after_setup_theme', 'mytheme_after_setup_init');

if ( ! function_exists( 'mytheme_after_setup_init' ) ){
    function mytheme_after_setup_init(){

    /********* Register sidebars ***********/
    require_once( get_template_directory(). 'inc/sidebars.php' );

    }
}
```

Comment: I understand the registering part, I just don't understand how to get my formatting and structure there. I don't think I am using any widgets, so that's where I am confused. I literally want the code I posted above to be my sidebar on all pages.

Comment: But by default, WordPress offers Search, Categories and Archive widget, so you're all set there. You can modify the `before_widget`, `after_widget`, `before_title` and `after_title` with the html that will wrap those elements.

Comment: But if I don't want to use widgets and use what I've programmed, how do I go about implementing that instead? That's what I am trying to figure out.

Comment: You can either put this in a page template (`page-yourname.php`) and then add it there. Plus `wp_list_cats()` has been deprecated, use `wp_list_categories()` instead.

Comment: So I could just say <?php include 'wpsidebar.php'; ?> at the bottom of my file and that would do the same thing?

Comment: In my playing around with this some more, I've discovered that include works for the sidebar, but the placement is off. I use a container to encapsulate post and the sidebar on a single post page, but I can't do this here because it gives me multiple sidebars. Any insights or tips to overcome this?